# jquery ajax success function

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var $stars = $("#formStars{{ item.url }}")
                    $stars.click(function(){
                        var value = $("input:radio[name={{ item.url }}]:checked", this).val(),
                            item = "{{ item.url }}",
                            user = "{{ user }}";

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/addvote/",
                            data: "item="+item+"&user="+user+"&value="+value,
                            success: function(){
                                $("input:radio[name="+item+"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                        });
                    });             
                </script>
```

Don't work the success function, input not disabled, but if i reload the page it becoms disabled...

Comment: is there any error in your console.use firbug

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your function in the a document.ready

```
$(document).ready(                    
                    var $stars = $("#formStars{{ item.url }}")
                    $stars.click(function(){
                        var value = $("input:radio[name={{ item.url }}]:checked", this).val(),
                            item = "{{ item.url }}",
                            user = "{{ user }}";

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/addvote/",
                            data: "item="+item+"&user="+user+"&value="+value,
                            success: function(){
                                $("input:radio[name="+item+"]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                            }
                        });
                    }); 
);
```

This makes sure the dom elements are loaded before attempting to manipulate them.